# Navigation Links Not wotking as Expected

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, directory

My Header navigation menu links are malfunctioning...

My project folder has 2-3 sub-folders. One of them is the "INCS" folder, which carry some files like the "HEADER.php","FOOTER.php" e.t.c. Another sub-folder "USER": Which is the folder that contains every file that that does processes on the user. For example the "USER" folder has the "WELCOME.php", "INDEX.php" files in it, which is where the user is redirected to after successful Login.

In the "WELCOME.php" file for example i included the "HEADER.php" file from the "INCS" sub-folder in this manner "../incs/header.php".

```
    <div class="probootstrap-loader"></div>

      <?php include '../incs/header.php'; ?>
      <!-- END: header -->
```

I expect that on the "WELCOME.php" page, when the user clicks on the "NAVIGATION LINKS" it should be like this structure "root/link.php" and that it should take the user to the "LINK" page, but when i hover on any of the links i get this structure "root/user/link.php".

Considering the fact that these other links are in the ROOT DIRECTORY not the SUB-FOLDERS..

I really hope someone understands this, because its the first time i am experiencing this issue and i don't know how best to explain it

Comment: For that you need to keep welcome.php outside user folder, so URL can be as you want, or else you can use any frameworks where URL re-routing can be possible Like CI, where you can customize it

Comment: If u use ../ that will go out 1 back folder so if u in user/inc it will give you user/ but if you use / that will take your main root try /link.php

Comment: Yes @Jaymin I onced has the "WELCOME.PHP" page in the root dirctory and it worked fine, buh i just wish i could achieve the result this other way

Comment: `.htaccess` comes to mind

Comment: @Kuya Yes... I kinda have heard about .htaccess on issues like this, buh i haven't tried it before... Maybe you can tell me how or direct me to a resource